# Unsettable & Unwritable properties are still mutable

Tags: javascript, oop, immutability

I am trying to create a property within a constructor function which is immutable except through a prototype function. I am trying to go off MDN documentation of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties. But there does not seem to be a way to make a property completely immutable. Consider a simple example:

```
function Test(){
    Object.defineProperties(this,{
        elems : { value : [] }
    })
}
Test.prototype.addElem = function(newElem){
    if (this.elems.indexOf(newElem) == -1){
        this.elems.push(newElem);
    }
};
```

which works fine in most cases (not assignable):

```
>a = new Test()
Object { , 1 more… }
>a.elems
Array [  ]
>a.elems = 10
10
>a.elems
Array [  ]
```

Unfortunately, it is still mutable. Consider:

```
>a.elems.push(10)
1
>a.elems
Array [ 10 ]
```

I am sure they are other functions (array or object methods?) that will change the value of a non-writeable & non-settable property. Push was just the one I ran into. Is there a way to accomplish this? I know that one possible solution is :

```
function Test(){
    var elems = [];
    this.addElem = function(newElem){
        if (elems.indexOf(newElem) == -1){
            elems.push(newElem);
        }
    }
}
```

But I have read this is memory-inefficient especially when there are many instances of the "class". Also, what I am working on may have many methods like this, so I am even more worried about memory considerations.

Any ideas? I am not super knowledgeable about all the intricacies of JS prototyping.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, objects are extensible by default, but if you're able to take advantage of ES5, you should be able to use the [`Object.seal()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) or [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) methods to get immutable properties.

The MDN docs for `Object.freeze()` have an example that shows how to recursively freeze ("deepFreeze") all of the properties of an object, effectively making it completely immutable.

Here's a proof of concept that combines the code in the question with the code from the docs:

```
function Test() {
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        elems : { value : [] }
    })
}

Test.prototype.addElem = function(newElem) {
    if (this.elems.indexOf(newElem) == -1) {
        this.elems.push(newElem);
    }
};

function deepFreeze(obj) {

  // Retrieve the property names defined on obj
  var propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);

  // Freeze properties before freezing self
  propNames.forEach(function(name) {
    var prop = obj[name];

    // Freeze prop if it is an object
    if (typeof prop == 'object' && prop !== null)
      deepFreeze(prop);
  });

  // Freeze self (no-op if already frozen)
  return Object.freeze(obj);
}

a = new Test();

a.elems.push(1);
console.log(a.elems); // [1]

deepFreeze(a);

a.elems.push(2);

console.log(a.elems); // Error
```

In FireBug, the `a.elems.push()` after the object is "deep frozen" returns a `TypeError` exception, indicating the property is not writable;

> TypeError: can't define array index property past the end of an array
>   with non-writable length

The Safari inspector also returns a `TypeError` exception:

> TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.

Comment: Just tried it and both of those failed. I am still able to push into the elems property. Not sure why? Might it be because I am sealing/freezing the object that contains the property instead of the property itself?

Comment: For the sake of documentation, I performed: a = Object.seal(new Test()); a.elems.push(1); And that did indeed push into a.elems. Same results with freeze.

Comment: @mhermher Got it! I think I misunderstood your question. I updated the answer to include some sample code that I think will solve your problem.

Comment: I might just go with something like this I guess. I was hoping there was some more elegant built in way to do this. Feels like it should be the default behavior when there is no setter.

Answer (score 0):

You can largely accomplish this with the help of a closure.  This is how you achieve privacy in JavaScript.

In a nutshell you create a variable inside of a function and have that function return an object that contains setters/getters.

In my example the foo function contains a _foo variable that can only be set by the methods in the object returned from function foo. You are effectively creating an API to the var held withing the function foo's scope.

```
var foo = function(config){

    if (!config) {
        config = {};
    }
//enclosed variable
    var _foo = {
        bar: []
    };

    if (config.bar) {//All item to be initialized with data
        _foo.bar = config.bar;
    }

    var fooAPI = {
        addBarItem: function(val){
            _foo.bar.push(val);
            return _foo.bar.length - 1;//return idenx of item added
        },
        removeBarItem: function(index) {
            return _foo.bar.slice(index, 1);//return the removed item
        },
        getBarItem: function(index) {
            return _foo.bar[index];//return the removed item
        },
        emptyBarItems: function() {
            return _foo.bar.slice(0, _foo.bar.length);//return all removed
        },
    getBarItems: function(){
        //clone bar do not return reference to it in order to keep private
        var newBar = [];
         _foo.bar.forEach(function(item){
             newBar.push(item);
            });
            return newBar;
        }
    };

    return fooAPI;
};

var myFoo = new foo({bar: ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']});
console.log(myFoo.getBarItems());
```

Comment: This is the approach I usually take but I keep reading that it memory inefficient because the API methods are redefined for each instantiation of the constructor. A lot of resources recommend using prototype extension. It seems that prototype extension basically disallows private members though. I was never formally trained in JS though, so all of its OOP stuff just seems weird to me still.

Comment: In JS, a closure is how you simulate privacy.